# can we fix handshake error from worldpay in a site having ssl?

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, https, handshake, worldpay

I have a site developed in codeigniter hosted with ssl. After successful payment transaction in WorldPay its not getting back to our site and we are getting an email from WorldPay saying that

```
 Error reported: Callback to: https://my_site/controller/function: failed CAUSED BY Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.
```

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```